# Ethereum node has low RPC performance

Tags: parity, json-rpc

I'm running an Ethereum Parity node on my home laptop (i7-7500U @2.7ghz, 2CPUs, w/ SSD) and getting massively more RPC throughput than on a dedicated Amazon AWS linux instance (i3.xlarge, 4vCPUs, w/ NVME SSD).

On my laptop, I can process ~500 "trace_transaction" calls per second, vs. around 100 on my AWS node. I assumed the node performance of my laptop and this i3.xlarge instance would be pretty similar.

I also tried bumping up --jsonrpc-threads and jsonrpc-server-threads and neither of them seemed to increase AWS RPC performance. My AWS vCPUs are nowhere near fully utilized.

Any ideas? Are there certain settings on Linux or on AWS I should look out for that could be causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: What rpc endpoint are you using, http, ws, or ipc?  I just posted an answer to [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23177/how-many-concurrent-requests-can-an-ethereum-node-handle/38614#38614), which gives benchmarks from one of our Parity nodes, on which we get >40k req/s via http, and >70k via ipc.  This is on bare metal, so no hypervisor; performance is much worse when we test on shared vps instances, but certainly much higher than 100 `trace_transaction` calls per sec.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion:

- Local connections are inherently faster (I would have thought order of magnitudes) than across a network.  You're straight to memory and processing with little transport (just localhost) adding ms latency.
- AWS somehow "throttling" the connection?  Any odd terms of service points about max connections?

This could all be rubbish...